# avoiding the display of dropdown value twice in edit

Tags: php, mysql

While editing the record from database, i display already selected value and option to select other values too. But i want to avoid already selected value to display twice in dropdown. Not getting how to do it

here is my code

```
<label class="control-label">Sales Area</label>
<?php
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM sales_area ORDER BY name";
$query5 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);
?>

<select name="area" class="form-control" required>
<option value="<?php echo $row['sales_area']; ?>"><?php echo $row['areaname']; ?></option>
<?php while ($rs5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query5)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $rs5["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs5["name"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

in `$row['sales_area']`, data already present in database, this should not display again.

Comment: So, `$row['sales_area']` is same as `$rs5["id"]`. Having Id. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haven't tested it, but should be something like this:

```
<select name="area" class="form-control" required>
<?php while ($rs5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query5)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $rs5["id"]; ?>" <?php if($rs5["id"] == $row['sales_area'] ) { echo "selected"; }  ?>  ><?php echo $rs5["name"]; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```